# В каких говорах русского языка происходила утрата звука 'р' в из суффиксов -арь/-ярь?

Tags: диалекты, диалектизмы

Если более конкретно, то меня интересует пара 'дегтярник'-'дег(х)тя(е)ник'
Насколько я понимаю, то суффиксы -ярь/-арь характерны для большинства русских говоров, но, при этом, в пермских говорах из них исчезла 'р'. К сожалению, у меня не вышло разузнать, откуда эта особенность попала в пермские говоры.

Одна из немногих зацепок, что могли бы натолкнуть на верный путь - в исходном говоре вместо 'дегтярник' скорее всего было 'дехтяник'. Это прослеживается по пермским фамилиям. В начале 17 века, когда русские там жили всего пару десятелетий, и собственным изменениям еще неоткуда взяться, по местным фамилиям уже прослеживается измененный вариант.

У меня есть предположение, что этими родительскими говорами было что-то северное, ввиду общего оканья в Пермском крае. Плюс в северо-западных русских говорах встречается форма 'дехоть' вместо 'деготь', что сочетается с 'дехтяник'.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь/совет в поисках ответов.

Comment: Тут возможно, не утрата суффикса, а просто другое, параллельное словообразование. Для иллюстрации рассмотрим три вполне возможных слова: нефтярь, нефтяник, нефтярник. Абсурдно утверждать, что в слове нефтяник исчез звук "р".